# Gmail Command Line Client in ruby

Tags: ruby, gmail, gmail-api

I am asked to create a gmail command line client in ruby to read,send and receive mails without using any libray or gem
Could anybody suggest me ways to do this?

I have searched for different ways online but all have been using gmail-api gem, basically i am tasked to create this particular gem only.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail has a [RESTful api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) and Ruby has a HTTP [module](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/stdlibs/net/Net/HTTP.html).
You should be able to use that module to access gmail without need for any gems or external libraries.

Comment: Could you please list down the steps that need to be done